# trying to close MatBottomSheet on Capacitor back button click

Tags: android, angular, mobile, angular-material, capacitor

I am using Capacitor to build an Angular web application for Android.
When clicking on the Android back button I want to close the MatBottomSheet by calling the 'dismiss' function on '_openedBottomSheetRef'.

In the next example the '_openedBottomSheetRef' is always set as null even if the MatBottomSheet is open but I am not sure why.

- I pasted only the relevant code pieces.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatBottomSheet} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {App} from '@capacitor/app';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.less'],
    animations: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private readonly bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscribeAppBackButton();
    }

    private subscribeAppBackButton(): void {
        App.addListener('backButton', this.closeBottomSheet.bind(this));
    }

    private async closeBottomSheet(): Promise<void> {
        this.bottomSheet._openedBottomSheetRef?.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.